# Hashmap not allowing integer as value

Tags: java, hashmap

My situation demands to add Integer to the Hashmap value because i need to sort the list based on the integer. I am doing like below

```
Map hmInspStatus = new HashMap();
hmInspStatus.put("Name",Integer.parseInt(strIRName.substring(2,strIRName.length())));
```

System is throwing an error message saying i can't add an integer to a HashMap. I referred some of the posts in the site and suggested to use a HashSet, but is it possible to add Key, value to HashSet?

Can anybody help me in achieving what i am looking for?

Thanks

Comment: Do you really intend to use raw types?

Comment: You can add key in Hash Set too. Remember when using collections you need to mention the Generics in which you should define what datatype you would like it to contain.

Comment: I tried Map hmInspStatus<String, Integer> = new HashMap<String, Integer>();. But compiler is throwing a syntax error saying.. "; is expected"..

Comment: @Balu that is because you have them in the wrong order. But it is better to use generics. Change it to: `Map<String, Integer> hmInspStatus`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modern Java uses [generic](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html) data structures. With the generic types given, Java will handle autoboxing of the primitive type.

```
Map<String, Integer> hmInspStatus = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
hmInspStatus.put("Name",Integer.parseInt(strIRName.substring(2,strIRName.length())));
```

Update: OP is using Java 1.3. This version not only does not support generics, it also does not support autoboxing. In that case, you have to skip the generics and use manual boxing, or directly construct the `Integer` from the `String`.

```
Map hmInspStatus = new HashMap();
hmInspStatus.put("Name", new Integer(strIRName.substring(2,strIRName.length())));
```

Comment: Client is using java 1.3, will the above code works using this version? because i am getting an error saying "not a statement".

Comment: @Balu, Generics were added in Java 1.5. If at all possible, you should upgrade the client software because generics are not the only thing missing from Java 1.3.

Answer (score 0):

Do:

```
Map hmInspStatus = new HashMap();
hmInspStatus.put("Name",(Integer)Integer.parseInt(strIRName.substring(2,strIRName.length())));
```